# does "taken" observables implicitly complete?

Tags: rxjs

Having
`obs1 = new Rx.Observable.interval(1000);
obs2 = obs1.take(2);`
`obs2` will complete after the second value emitted by `obs1`.
what about `obs1` ?
will it complete as well or will it keep on firing?

Answer (score 0):

The `take` operator returns a new observable sequence that has no effect on the operation of the source observable sequence produced by `Rx.Observable.interval`. And since `Rx.Observable.interval`  is a "hot" observable, `obs1` will keep emitting values even after `obs2` has completed.

```js
var obs1 = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);
obs1.subscribe(function(x) { document.write("obs1: " + x + '<br \>'); }, null, function(x) { document.write("obs1 completed" + '<br \>'); });
var obs2 = obs1.take(2);
obs2.subscribe(function(x) { document.write("obs2: " + x + '<br \>'); }, null, function(x) { document.write("obs2 completed" + '<br \>'); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/2.5.2/rx.all.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're conflating "hot" with non-terminating. `Interval` keeps producing values because it is a different sequence, a cold sequence, as each subscription creates a new periodic scheduling which is independent of the others.

Comment: @paulpdaniels But that's an implementation detail. The semantics are still "hot":

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the semantics. A hot observable is one that will produce values regardless of the whether it has any subscribers. Interval will not continue to produce values when you dispose of your subscription.  You can see this by disposing of the subscription to `obs1` and resubscribing a half second later.  If it were hot you should see an event after 500 ms.

Comment: @OliverWeichhold why do you think `Rx.Observable.interval` produces a hot source?